# Returning majority of array elements in QGIS expression

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression

I need to identify the majority of a string in an attribute field. For example `'A,AB,C,A' -> 'A'`

Since QGIS 3.18 the function `array_majority()` is available.

However, I use the latest stable version 3.16 and I am wondering if something similar can be done?

Something like:

```
array_to_string(majority(string_to_array("sumEHZ")))
```

Comment: So `AB` should be considered to be different from `A`? Like: `'A, AB, A, AB, C, AB' -> AB`? Why not updating to QGIS 3.22?

Comment: Exactly, `AB` is different from `A` or `B`. If it is too complicated I'll probably have to update...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In QGIS 3.16, you can use this expression, where `text` is the field containing the text you want to replace:

```
with_variable (
    'var',
    'array_foreach (
        array_distinct (string_to_array ("text")),
        with_variable (
            ''arr'',
               @element,
               array_length (
                array_filter (
                    string_to_array("text"),
                       @element=@arr
                )
            )
        )
    )',
    array_get (
        array_distinct (string_to_array("text")),
        array_find (
            eval(@var),
            array_get (
                array_sort (
                    eval(@var),0
                ),0
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Expression edited, the repeating part from the initial expression is created as a variable `var` and called twice with `eval(@var)` to make the expression a bit shorter. See the screenshot for the (otherwise unchanged) initial expression:
[image]